# Xcode (storyboards and segues): why delegates instead of references?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, reference, delegates, protocols

I have read the [following tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2) regarding storyboard.

Basically the sample App created in this tutorial let the user navigate between various views and it's created using **segue**.

In order to navigate between views the tutorial say to create two UITableViewController and when "going" from one to another to specify a delegate:

First controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddPlayer"])
    {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        PlayerDetailsViewController *playerDetailsViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        playerDetailsViewController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Second controller:

```
@protocol PlayerDetailsViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)playerDetailsViewControllerDidCancel: (PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller;
- (void)playerDetailsViewController: (PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller didAddPlayer:(Player *)player;

@end

@interface PlayerDetailsViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <PlayerDetailsViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

When "going back":

```
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate playerDetailsViewControllerDidCancel:self];
}
```

My simple question is why this complication? Why use delegates and protocols?

I have changed the code using a "Java" style and now I'm passing to the second controller a reference to the first one, everything is working.

First controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
...
        playerDetailsViewController.playerViewController = self;
}
```

Second controller:

```
@property (strong, readwrite) PlayerViewController *playerViewController;
```

So, what are the benefits to use delegates instead of simply passing references between ViewControllers?

Thanks!

Guido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put in a Java manner, if you use a strong type you are tied to a single class.
Instead the delegate is in the end a class conform to a protocol.
So you could pass many class as delegates to playerDetail, as long as they are conform to the @protocol.

Is like casting and passing interface instead of concrete class in java.
You may well know the List interface and all the ArrayList, LinkedList... etc concrete implementations.

One thing I don't understand is why they get destination controller by passing trough the navigation. I always used:

```
MyDestinationViewController *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];
```

so that you can use in many situation where you do not have a navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

Several reasons:

- [As Leonardo says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9619898/2998), using references you couple the two view controllers together unnecessarily. You should just pass the data that's required and not the whole class
- This is just how Objective-C apps tend to be constructed. By using a different method you'd be making your app harder to understand by seasoned developers
- (You don't always need the delegate in your second class -- for example when it's display only -- so your example code is more complex than is often the case)

Related to the last point, your code is already harder than it needs to be. `UIStoryboardSegue` has properties pointing to the source and destination view controllers; there's no need to mess with the navigation controller.

Comment: Re the last point - if the destination VC is embedded in a navigation controller (as opposed to being within the same navigation stack as the current controller) then you _do_ need all that mess

Comment: @jrturton Yes, you're right. I misread the code initially. Still, the code presented is more complex than the most common case (I think).